# Can you override a library's Spring property placeholders?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

We are working on moving our application to use only Spring-Boot application.properties files. The old way we were doing was that each library/dependency would have their properties stored in a dedicated properties file like `res/environment/some-library-override.properties`. The values would then be retrieved in the library using `@Value("$some-library-{PROPERTY_NAME}")`.

However, since moving all of these override properties to dedicated application.properties files, it is no longer resolving the properties and we get errors like `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$some-library-{PROPERTY_NAME}"`.

I assume this is because it is still expecting the property to be in that dedicated properties file.

Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve modifying the library/dependency? Is it possible to have it ignore the prefix and only look for the PROPERTY_NAME in the application.properties files?

Answer (score 0):

if you have declared propertie var like`property.name=XXXX` or added environment var like `PROPERTY_NAME=XXXX`.

you need to use this way

```java
@Value("some-library-${property.name}")
// will inject value "some-library" + "XXXX"
```